# A-Data firmware remains old after update

Tags: ssd, boot-camp, firmware, flashing

I'm running A-Data S599 SSD on my Apple Mac Pro running Windows 7 64-bit Ultimate in Apple BootCamp.

The flasher is updating the drive ok, but when it finish I got BSOD. After rebooting the system I got the same firmware.

My current version is: 3.4.3 and I'm updating to 3.6.5.

Comment: This is not an Apple product so it's not related to Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was chipset problem. I've got a new Mac Pro 2009 now with ICH10R and it flashed nicely.